# BLE Timeout with terminate_gap_procedure using BLUENRG

Tags: c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluenrg

I am developing an IOT solution using the BLUENRG-M0 from ST.

I am coding in C and I use a custom board with SPI communication between the BLUENRG and my MSP430F5255 from T.I . I am using the ACI API to transmit commands to the BLE module.

I have 2 boards, and while one is advertising, I want the other to perform scanning in order to receive an advertising report. (And to get the RSSI after).

My issue is when I want to make another scan. I use the aci_gap_terminate_gap_procedure() with the good opcode link to the function that I use for scanning, but I always receive a BLE_Timeout error. Therefore my primary scan has not ended correctly and I can’t begin a new one.

I have tried increasing the time before TIMEOUT but nothing changes.

I didn’t see people talking about the issue with the gap_terminate function, so I ask this here.

It would be nice if someone could clarify for me the use of this function and why it has this behavior.

Best regards.

PS: Here is the [link](https://documentation.help/BlueNRG-MS/group___g_a_p___functions.html#gae2ea5bc326273ee5daf83d7a2229c498) for the documentation of BLUENRG API

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To clarify, I just want a simple way to reset my BLE scans in order to achieve a new one. For me the this API function is the only way but maybe there is as an alternative ?